# Finding numbers with decimal comma in a TeX-File using regular expressions

Tags: regex, tex

I have a very large TeX-File wherein we set mathematical text. Unfortunately, TeX sets a empty space after each comma, even though numbers (in Germany) are formatted without space after comma.

I am aware that there are packages that solve this problem automatically, but I tried to find such commas with a regular expression before the TeX formatter would do its thing, so I could wrap these commas in braces. For example, I want `1,2` to become `1{,}2`. But my regular expression approach does not work as expected:

I used "[0-9],[0-9]" resp. "\d,\d" to look for all places where two digits are separated with a decimal comma. That works fine. But I was wondering why for input "1,2,3" it only finds the match "1,2" but not "2,3".

There must be something I don't quite understand about regular expressions. How would I have to alter the expression to find overlapping instances of the search pattern?

Comment: After rendering "1,1" will be set as "1, 1". to avoid this, i have to either use a package or have to write "1{,}1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a character has been matched, it is not matched again. As in your example "2" is matched, the "cursor" of the regex engine has now *passed* that "2", and so the next match can only be found in ",3" -- and there no match is found.

To resolve that, use a look-ahead assertion for the decimal digits without actually capturing them:

```
\d,(?=\d)
```

The matches will be "1," and "2," and now you can make the replacement as you want (adding braces), knowing these matches guarantee there is a digit following.